# How to interpret the current function value in the logistic regression from the statsmodel api?

Tags: logistic, statsmodels

Whenever I train a logistic regression model with the `statsmodel` api, it always feeds back a message similair to this one:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.613427
         Iterations 6
```

How should I interpret this value? Is it the accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary least squares linear regression, there is a closed-form solution for the parameter estimate: $\hat\beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. Logistic regression lacks such a closed-form solution, so numerical methods are required to find the parameter vector that minimizes the loss function.

The `Current function value` is the value of the loss function when you use the parameters found by your fit.

The `Iterations` is the number of times a process in the numerical optimization had to be repeated in order to reach the solution.

Terminating `successfully` means that the numerical optimization converged on a solution and is not still bouncing around, trying to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks Dave! One question, could you explain to me why  ̂ =()−1 is not a numerical method?

Comment: By numerical method, I mean some way to approximate the solution. When we do OLS, we can derive $\hat\beta_{ols}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ by using calculus, and that is the exact right answer. In logistic regression, we have to resort to approximations.